# horizontal scrollbar even after removing css

Tags: css, scrollbar

My footer is full width on some pages and on others it matches the content width. On pages where the footer is full width, a horizontal scroll bar appears. I'm not sure why this is happening and researched loads. Because every answer was associated with css, I decided to take all the css out just to see if there was something in the code that was causing it... but I'm baffled because even with all coding removed and refreshed, the horizontal bar still comes up on a few pages. Is it really css issue?

Comment: Difficult to say without code. There are a lot of things that can happen, and if it only occurs on some pages it could be a case where certain content overflows it's container horizontally and you're just not seeing it.

Comment: Yes, it is CSS related issue, but you should post code snippets of where you think the problem is

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the horizontal scroll bar using css:

```
 body {
   overflow-x: hidden;
 }
```